# How do I add HTML elements into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, element

I'm making a piano simulator and want to have buttons on each key that play the note when clicked. I used the button html element to make the sound play, as I've heard this is the best way to do it and it wouldn't work if I used the JavaScript button object.

this is the JS code and it works just fine to play the sound when clicked.

```
let cButton = document.getElementById("cButton"); 

cButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  C.play();
})
```

However the buttons are all up at the top of the page because they are html elements and I'm not sure how to add them into the JS code so they can be moved to the keys.

This is the output of my code. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP4gH.png)

EDIT: This is my HTML and CSS code as well, as some have been asking for it.

```
    <button id="cButton">C</button>
    <button id="dButton">D</button>
    <button id="eButton">E</button>
    <button id="fButton">F</button>
    <button id="gButton">G</button>
    <button id="aButton">A</button>
    <button id="bButton">B</button>
```

This is just creating all the buttons.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

Note, the CSS code isn't my own, it was there when I opened the file. I've tried messing around with it a bit, but all it does is change things inside the white bar at the top where the buttons are.

Comment: Hi can you post your HTML as well? also your CSS if you have any

Comment: Yes, I just edited the post!

Comment: Your HTML gives us the buttons, what about the keys?

Comment: Where does the `C.play();` come from? Are you using the native Web Audio API directly or a library for it? You might want to give each button a `data-` attribute to keep track of each note being played, and use it to invoke the `.play()` call. That is, each `button` could have `data-note="C"`, `data-note="D"`, etc as its unique value, and when clicked it could trigger the respective note to play. For a more comprehensive answer, we'd need a more comprehensive code snippet as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If your buttons ***work fine*** then ***style*** *them* to look like the piano image you have linked to.

Comment: @JonP Essentially I'm just trying to put buttons onto the keys that I've drawn so I didn't think I'd really need them. The piano is just a drawing. If there's a somewhat easy way of coding it so that I can just click on a key and it plays the note without a button then that would be great, but I'm very new to JS and new-ish to HTML so I'm trying to make this as simple as possible.

Comment: @BumhanYu `The C.play();` is just for an mp3 file that I've downloaded to my computer and loaded into the project. `function preload() {
  soundFormats("mp3");
  C = loadSound("C.mp3");}` This is my code for loading it in.

Comment: You could *overlay* the keys onto the image by setting the image as a background to a parent element and setting its position to relative, then set your keys positions to absolute, use the left and top properties as well as width and height to set up an ***overlay*** of the keys...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JSX, it's pretty much a framework that allows you to write HTML elements and combine it with JS. You can create a variable that represents a key of the piano and then use JS to assign each sound value to each different key.

Comment: JSX is a syntax extension for developers using the React library. Since OP isn't using React, this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the following html snippet inside our page:

```
<div id="key1">
</div>
<div id="key2">
</div>
..etc for each key
```

If I wanted to add a button element on the div key1 element I could use the innerHtml property.

```
document.getElementById("key1").innerHtml = `<button key="mybutton" onclick="dostuff()"> MyButton </button`
```

You can investigate more into how you can do this on Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

You can probably do this with other DOM properties.

It has been awhile since I have done vanilla JS, I usually do React so hopefully this is not rusty code :). It would also help if you could post some HTML so we can see how your entire project looks.

Comment: This is all I've got for HTML so far. `<button id="cButton">C</button>
    <button id="dButton">D</button>
    <button id="eButton">E</button>
    <button id="fButton">F</button>
    <button id="gButton">G</button>
    <button id="aButton">A</button>
    <button id="bButton">B</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these codes:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>------------ CodeSpeedy ----------</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <!-- white and black keys -->
    <div data-note="C" class="key white black" ><h3>C</h3></div>
    <div data-note="O" class="key white black" ><h3>O</h3></div>
    <!-- white keys -->
    <div data-note="D" class="key white" ><h3>D</h3></div>
     <!-- white and black keys -->
    <div data-note="E" class="key white black" ><h3>E</h3></div>
    <div data-note="S" class="key white black" ><h3>S</h3></div>
    <div data-note="P" class="key white black" ><h3>P</h3></div>
    <!-- white keys -->
    <div data-note="E1" class="key white" ><h3>E</h3></div>
     <!-- white and black keys -->
    <div data-note="E" class="key white black" ><h3>E</h3></div>
    <div data-note="D" class="key white black" ><h3>D</h3></div>
    <!-- white keys -->
    <div data-note="Y" class="key white" ><h3>Y</h3></div>
   </div>  

    <!-- Audio files -->
   <audio id="C" src="music/tune0.mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="O" src="music/tune (1).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="D" src="music/tune (2).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="E" src="music/tune (3).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="S" src="music/tune (4).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="P" src="music/tune (5).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="E1" src="music/tune (4).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="E" src="music/tune (3).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="D" src="music/tune (2).mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="Y" src="music/tune (1).mp3"></audio>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
body {
    background: rgba(39, 34, 34, 0.986);
  }
  
h1{
    color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
  }

h3{
    margin-top: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
  }

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  
.white {
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    width: 10%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 2px;
  }
  
.white.black:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(17, 11, 11);
    right: -25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

**script.js**

```
const WHITE=['a','s','d','f','j','k','k'];
const BLACK=['r','t','y','u','i'];
let keys=document.querySelectorAll('.key');
let blackKeys=document.querySelectorAll('.key.black');
let whiteKeys=document.querySelectorAll('.key.white');

// eventlistener for mouse click
keys.forEach(key =>{
key.addEventListener('click',()=>playMusic(key));
});
//eventlistener for key press using keydown
document.addEventListener('keydown',e=>{
let key=e.key;
let whiteKeyIndex=WHITE.indexOf(key);
let blackKeyIndex=BLACK.indexOf(key);

if(whiteKeyIndex>-1) playMusic(whiteKeys[whiteKeyIndex]);
if(blackKeyIndex>-1) playMusic(blackKeys[blackKeyIndex])
});

// this function will play audio
function playMusic(key){
    const audio=document.getElementById(key.dataset.note);
    audio.currentTime=0;
    audio.play();
}
```

It will provide you with an HTML page that contains a piano keyboard simulator with sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to place the keys over the top of the image, you can use **position** ***absolute*** with **top** and **left** properties as well as *psuedo elements* to style the keys to ***overlay*** over the image.

In my example I only code the C and D keys, if you expand the snippit to **full page** and press anywhere on the C or D you will get the event to trigger a console log of the dataset-id value.

```js
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys')

function showNote(e){
  console.log(e.target.dataset.id)
  // your play code can go here, use the dataset.id of the event.target to get the note
}

keys.forEach(note => note.addEventListener('click', showNote))
```

```css
#main {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHa3G.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#cButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 37px;
  height: 340px;
  width: 45px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; uncomment to see the key outline and comment out opacity */
  opacity: 0;
}

#cButton:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 42px;
  height: 127px;
  width: 30px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; uncomment to see the key outline and comment out opacity */
  opacity: 0;
}

#dButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 130px;
  height: 340px;
  width: 45px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; uncomment to see the key outline and comment out opacity */
  opacity: 0;
}

#dButton:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: -18px;
  height: 127px;
  width: 15px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; uncomment to see the key outline and comment out opacity */
  opacity: 0;
}

#dButton:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 42px;
  height: 127px;
  width: 15px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; uncomment to see the key outline and comment out opacity */
  opacity: 0;
}

/* keep styling your keys to fill them in by targeting their unique ids and using before and after psuedo elements to style the ends of the whole keys (white keys)
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <button data-id="c" class="keys" id="cButton" title="right click me and click 'inspect' to see the element in your console inspector, then open the button parent element and hover over the element and its psuedo elements in your inspector to see the highlighted elements/psuedo elements in your browser window =)">C</button>
    <button data-id="d" class="keys" id="dButton">D</button>
    <button data-id="e" class="keys" id="eButton">E</button>
    <button data-id="f" class="keys" id="fButton">F</button>
    <button data-id="g" class="keys" id="gButton">G</button>
    <button data-id="a" class="keys" id="aButton">A</button>
    <button data-id="b" class="keys" id="bButton">B</button>
</div>
```